# How to add permission for users who have staff status

Tags: python, django, permissions, mixins, django-users

```
I need something that only admins and staff could delete users. When I use this, only admins can do it, if I try to delete a user with staff status, I get an error 403, how i can fix it? ty.`
```

```
class DriverDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = Driver
    success_url = reverse_lazy("taxi:driver-list")
    permission_required = "taxi.delete-driver"
```

```
`
```

i`m try add sum permission in admin panel, but its work only in admin page.